# Explicitly specifying the TaskScheduler for an implicitly scheduled method

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

I have the following method which uses implicit scheduling:

```
private async Task FooAsync()
{
   await Something();
   DoAnotherThing();
   await SomethingElse();
   DoOneLastThing();
}
```

However, from one particular call-site I want it run on a low-priority scheduler instead of the default:

```
private async Task BarAsync()
{
   await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => await FooAsync(), 
      ...,
      ...,
      LowPriorityTaskScheduler);
}
```

How do I achieve this? It seems like a really simple ask, but I'm having a complete mental block!

*Note: I'm aware the example won't actually compile :)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your own `TaskFactory` instance, initialized with the scheduler you want. Then call `StartNew` on that instance:

```
TaskScheduler taskScheduler = new LowPriorityTaskScheduler();
TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory(taskScheduler);
...
await taskFactory.StartNew(FooAsync);
```

Comment: If you need to get a return from the await, you should also unwrap it, ie await taskFactory.StartNew(FooAsync).Unwrap;

Comment: May you add a code or reference for the `LowPriorityTaskScheduler`?

Comment: @xmedeko: `LowPriorityTaskScheduler` is the op's type, not mine.

Answer (score -1):

You can set thread-priority, but within the thread's method:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
```

Check other values of `ThreadPriority` enum.